# Why does MySQL consecutive JOIN give an unexpected result?

Tags: mysql, join

I had 3 tables which were `Category`, `Product` and `Vendor`. Then I tried to make a consecutive join 3 tables in 1 query to count the product for each category.

If a product or it's vendor is deleted, it will be excluded from the list. Moreover, if there was no product available, I still need to keep the category with the 0 count result. Because all tables are using the soft-delete strategy, I need to filter deleted items from the Query to get a proper count result. Then, the problem start from here.

A quick sample is below

```
Category
--|----------|----------|
id|name      |deleted_at|
--|----------|----------|
 1|Food      |      NULL|
 2|Stationery|      NULL|

Product
--|-------|---------|------|----------|
id|cate_id|vendor_id|name  |deleted_at|
--|-------|---------|------|----------|
 1|      1|        1|Bread |      NULL|
 2|      1|        2|Milk  |      NULL|
 5|      2|        2|Pencil|      NULL|

Vendor
--|-------|----------|
id|name   |deleted_at|
--|-------|----------|
 1|Woolies|      NULL|
 2|Cole   |2020-01-18|
```

Query1 gave an unexpected result

```
SELECT
    c.id AS cate_id,
    c.name AS cate_name,
    COUNT(p.id) AS total_product
FROM
    category c
LEFT JOIN product p 
    ON p.cate_id = c.id AND p.deleted_at IS NULL
INNER JOIN vendor v
    ON v.id = p.vendor_id AND v.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id;

cate_id|cate_name|total_product|
-------|---------|-------------|
      1|Food     |            1|
```

Query2 gave a correct response.

```
SELECT
    c.id AS cate_id,
    c.name AS cate_name,
    COUNT(p.id) AS total_product
FROM
    category c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p1.* FROM product p1 INNER JOIN vendor v ON v.id = p1.vendor_id AND v.deleted_at IS NULL) 
    AS p ON p.cate_id = c.id AND p.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id;

cate_id|cate_name |total_product|
-------|----------|-------------|
      1|Food      |            1|
      2|Stationery|            0|
```

I'm not likely sure but I guess the `Query1` did the `LEFT JOIN` between `Category` & `Product` tables first, then did the `INNER JOIN` on the JOINED Record & `Vendor`, finally leading to an unexpected result. Am I correct?

Is there any way to achieve this purpose without using a sub-query?

Comment: Without enabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY the result of such query is NOT deterministic. When the column/expression is listed in SELECT without aggregate ffunction, and it is absent in grouping expression, then its value will be taken from ANY row in a group. In shown query it is `p.id` column.

Comment: Inner join output only those records which have the records matched joinjing conditions in all source tables wheneas left join needs matching in left table only.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I already updated my question so that it wouldn't cause the problem of the sql_mode= ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Actually, my intention of the SELECT p.id is only demonstration which I think will make the example easy to understand, but it might unnecessary.

Comment: Take a look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b3e677ac269814ac9cadb2d9343cc27) and switch between MySQL 8.0 and 5.6 - see the difference in your queries - it demonstrates @Akina 's point about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` - which is a real trap for the unwary!

Comment: @Vérace Thanks for your detail explanation. I already updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT c.id AS cate_id, c.name AS cate_name, COUNT(p.id) AS total_product
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN ( Product p 
            INNER JOIN Vendor v ON v.id = p.vendor_id AND v.deleted_at IS NULL 
            ) ON p.cate_id = c.id AND p.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id, c.name;
```

or

```
SELECT c.id AS cate_id, c.name AS cate_name, COUNT(p.id) AS total_product
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN Vendor v ON v.id = p.vendor_id AND v.deleted_at IS NULL 
RIGHT JOIN Category c ON p.cate_id = c.id AND p.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id, c.name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9ed2ce096b8c2f3bafd5f62a33a2aab)

---

> I guess the Query1 did the LEFT JOIN between Category & Product first, then did the INNER JOIN on the JOINED Record & Vendor, finally leading to an unexpected result. Am I correct?

Yes, if at least one outer joining is present then tables scanning is performed in query text ordering (like STRAIGHT_JOIN is used).

---

> It would be really thankful if you can suggest a name or a link so that I can do some research about it.

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  JOIN Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Thanks for your impressive answer. Specific to your Query1, this is the first time I see a LEFT JOIN technique like this. It would be really thankful if you can suggest a name or a link so that I can do some research about it.

Comment: @TuanVu Link added.